# Shopify liquid access to article object from handle

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to display the title of blog posts but the only thing that renders me is ulr addresses.
This is how I display links from metafields:

```
{% for field in product.metafields.custom.related_product_with_blog_post.value %}
  <div><a href="{{ field.url }}">{{ field.url }}</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

How to get to article object and display all article titles from metafields?

Answer (score 0):

You already have your article object inside of the `field` variable. To fetch the blog post/ article's handle, just use `field.handle`.

See all available properties for the `article` object in the [Shopify API docs](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/article).

Comment: {% for field in product.metafields.custom.related_product_with_blog_post.value %}
  <div><a href="{{ field.url }}">{{ field.title}}</a></div>
{% endfor %} return nothing :/

Comment: Are you sure the `related_product_with_blog_post` metafield allows multiple values (a list) ? You can check the metafield definition to confirm that. If it only accepts a single value then you don't need to access the `value` property. Just use `product.metafields.custom.related_product_with_blog_post` without a for loop.

Comment: My code returns me 2 url blog posts because that's how many metafields I have completed so far and now I have to take blog-handle and article-handle from it.

Comment: As stated in my answer, you can access any information about the article in the [article object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/article)'s properties. The object has a `handle` property. That might be what you're looking for.